# EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt, possible key generation issue in Android

Tags: android, encryption, passwords, encryption-symmetric

So I'm having issues with generating a key from a string-based passphrase. The encryption step works fine and the decryption step works up until the error listed at the bottom, leaving the decrypted file corrupt. I use the following functions to perform the encryption/decryption:

```
public static boolean decryptFileFromUri(Context context, Uri file, String keyphrase) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(context, file));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        File ef = new File(f.toString().replace(".epf", ""));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ef);

        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Decrypting: " + f.toString());

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(keyphrase.getBytes("UTF8"));
        /*KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(rawKey);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] key = skey.getEncoded();*/
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();

        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Decrypted to: " + ef.toString());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean encryptFileFromUri(Context context, Uri file, String keyphrase) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(context, file));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        File ef = new File(f.toString() + ".epf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ef);

        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Encrypting: " + f.toString());

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(keyphrase.getBytes("UTF8"));
        /*KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(rawKey);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] key = skey.getEncoded();*/
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();
        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Encrypted to: " + ef.toString());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here's the function that generates the raw key:

```
private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();

    String result = "";
    for(int index = 0; index < raw.length; index++) {
        result += Integer.toHexString(raw[index]);
        // maybe you have to convert your byte to int before this can be done
        // (cannot check reight now)
    }

    Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Passphrase: " + new String(seed).toString() + " Key: " + result );
    return raw;
}
```

The output for the "test" input string is as follows for the above hex-dump of the key:

Encryption:

```
    04-17 09:01:25.088 18341-18341/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics D/HIDEMYPICS: Encrypting: /storage/emulated/0/Download/bailout_5128280_GIFSoup.com-1.gif
04-17 09:01:25.088 18341-18341/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics D/HIDEMYPICS: Passphrase: test Key: ffffff85affffffe21023ffffffb7ffffffe8ffffffc8214031fffffffa5b29ffffff9affffff80
```

Decryption:

```
04-17 09:01:43.808 18341-18341/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics D/HIDEMYPICS: Decrypting: /storage/emulated/0/Download/bailout_5128280_GIFSoup.com-1.gif.epf
04-17 09:01:43.808 18341-18341/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics D/HIDEMYPICS: Passphrase: test Key: ffffff8331ffffffe2ffffff87ffffffe242dffffffa61cffffffc7ffffffb4ffffffa1d74ffffff9affffff9b
```

Both decryption and encryption were seeded with "test" as the passphrase and yet the function returns 2 different keys and this is why I think I'm getting the bad-decrypt error, full trace of which is listed below:

```
    04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err: java.io.IOException: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.close(CipherOutputStream.java:136)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at com.dcheeseman.hidemypics.AESUtils.decryptFileFromUri(AESUtils.java:102)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at com.dcheeseman.hidemypics.HideMyPics.onActivityResult(HideMyPics.java:35)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6808)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4698)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:197)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1730)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
04-17 09:33:24.158 823-823/com.dcheeseman.hidemypics W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this issue!

Comment: Delete unused code from the question.

Comment: You state: "2 different keys", the keys must be the same so the area to debug is the key derivation `getRawKey`. Also check how the IV is being created and passed to the decryption, you will need to study the library documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You state: "2 different keys", the keys must be the same.

Typically you pre-share a key or password and if you use a password derive a key from it with a function such as PBKDF2. If you use password derivation you must use the same **deterministic** function on both encryption and decryption. The function used must produce the same key from the password on each side. Since you are using a random generator the derivation is not deterministic and this can not work.

Comment: Doesn't setting the seed on the secure random function as a way of forcing the algorithm to be deterministic? The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to use a deterministic function and it's generating different keys every time I run it.

Comment: Not for Cryptographic PRNGs, they are seeded and re-seeded from events on the system. Use PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function 2), that is what it is designed to do. PBKDF2 also requires an iteration count to make the computation to take longer, that is desirable for key derivation to delay attackers multiple attempts, use a value that results in about 100ms for the derivation.

Comment: Took your advice and found docs to get PBKDF2 and it fixed the key generation issue. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Took Zaph's advice and swapped over to PBKDF2 and now have consistent key generation.  Here's the code for anyone that's curious.

```
public static SecretKey generateKey(Context c, char[] passphraseOrPin) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    // Number of PBKDF2 hardening rounds to use. Larger values increase
    // computation time. You should select a value that causes computation
    // to take >100ms.
    byte[] salt = Settings.Secure.getString(c.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID).getBytes();

    final int iterations = 1000;

    final int outputKeyLength = 128;

    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphraseOrPin, salt, iterations, outputKeyLength);
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Secret Key: " + toHex(secretKey.getEncoded()) );
    return secretKey;
}

public static boolean decryptFileFromUri(Context context, Uri file, String keyphrase) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(context, file));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        File ef = new File(f.toString().replace(".epf", ""));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ef);

        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Decrypting: " + f.toString());

        SecretKey key = generateKey(context, keyphrase.toCharArray());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();

        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Decrypted to: " + ef.toString());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean encryptFileFromUri(Context context, Uri file, String keyphrase) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(context, file));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        File ef = new File(f.toString() + ".epf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ef);

        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Encrypting: " + f.toString());

        SecretKey key = generateKey(context, keyphrase.toCharArray());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();
        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Encrypted to: " + ef.toString());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

NOTE: It is still not working 100%, having issues where it's corrupting the first few bytes during decryption, resulting in corrupt file headers. If you want to see the results for that I've started a separate question post for that here: [CipherOutputStream corrupting headers in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680037/cipheroutputstream-corrupting-headers-in-android)