# CipherOutputStream corrupting headers in Android

Tags: android, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric, pbkdf2

I'm using a simple CipherInput/OutputStream to try to encrypt/decrypt files in android.

The problem I'm having is that it seems to be corrupting the first few bytes of the file but not the rest.  Here's an example of an output from a simple text file:

Original Text:

```
"Test for Android cipher. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

Cycled through Encryption and Decryption:

```
@ÍØJ­b¢çc°ÌHOšpher. The quick brown fox jumps over the the lazy dog.
```

Here's my code:

```
public static SecretKey generateKey(Context c, char[] passphraseOrPin) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    // Number of PBKDF2 hardening rounds to use. Larger values increase
    // computation time. You should select a value that causes computation
    // to take >100ms.
    byte[] salt = Settings.Secure.getString(c.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID).getBytes();

    final int iterations = 1000;

    final int outputKeyLength = 128;

    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphraseOrPin, salt, iterations, outputKeyLength);
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Secret Key: " + toHex(secretKey.getEncoded()) );
    return secretKey;
}

public static boolean decryptFileFromUri(Context context, Uri file, String keyphrase) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(context, file));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        File ef = new File(f.toString().replace(".epf", ""));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ef);

        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Decrypting: " + f.toString());

        SecretKey key = generateKey(context, keyphrase.toCharArray());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();

        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Decrypted to: " + ef.toString());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean encryptFileFromUri(Context context, Uri file, String keyphrase) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(context, file));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        File ef = new File(f.toString() + ".epf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ef);

        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Encrypting: " + f.toString());

        SecretKey key = generateKey(context, keyphrase.toCharArray());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();
        Log.d("HIDEMYPICS","Encrypted to: " + ef.toString());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

UPDATE:

Was advised to explicitly add a random IV to the cipher setup and added/modified the following lines of code to facilitate it:

```
SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
        r.nextBytes(ivBytes);

        SecretKey key = generateKey(context, keyphrase.toCharArray());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
```

Ended up with the same result. First few bytes of the text file were still corrupted.

FINAL ANSWER:

Not sure what I did, but per suggestions below I had tried a static IV and it had still exhibited the same behavior, but I moved the declaration and something happened; probably had a typo somewhere. The issue is now resolved though and here's the final working code. Thanks all that helped out!

```
private static final byte[] ivBytes = {109,15,57,79,75,112,50,91,18,18,107,127,65,68,12,69};

public static SecretKey generateKey(Context c, char[] passphraseOrPin) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    // Number of PBKDF2 hardening rounds to use. Larger values increase
    // computation time. You should select a value that causes computation
    // to take >100ms.
    byte[] salt = Settings.Secure.getString(c.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID).getBytes();

    final int iterations = 1000;

    final int outputKeyLength = 128;

    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphraseOrPin, salt, iterations, outputKeyLength);
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    return secretKey;
}

public static boolean decryptFileFromUri(Context context, Uri file, String keyphrase) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(context, file));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        File ef = new File(f.toString().replace(".epf", ""));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ef);

        SecretKey key = generateKey(context, keyphrase.toCharArray());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
            fos.write(d, 0, b);
            fos.flush();
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        fos.close();
        cis.close();

        f.delete();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean encryptFileFromUri(Context context, Uri file, String keyphrase) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(context, file));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        File ef = new File(f.toString() + ".epf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ef);

        SecretKey key = generateKey(context, keyphrase.toCharArray());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
            cos.flush();
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.close();
        fis.close();
        f.delete();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly set a random IV and include it with your ciphertext.

Comment: Tried that, and unfortunately didn't work :/. Same result. The first few bytes of the file are corrupted. Added an update above regarding it.

Comment: It's one sentence with about 11 words, and you still manage to only read the first part of it. The IV must be the same during encryption and decryption.

Comment: I'll try to get an example of the ciphertext up, but it encrypts the whole message front to back; what you're seeing is the decrypted message. I also tried using a static 128 bit IV vice the above random setup and still no joy.

Comment: Strange because it certainly *looks* like only the first block is corrupted. That's almost certainly an issue with the IV (unless the ciphertext block itself became corrupt somehow). So you explicitly set the same static IV for both encryption / decryption side and made absolutely sure you used the generated ciphertext, right?

Comment: Not sure what I did, moved the declaration of the static IV and it worked; probably had a typo somewhere.  Final working version of the code is posted in the OP.

Comment: Note that static IV's are not secure as the (first) ciphertext blocks would be identical if you'd use the same plaintext, key and IV. That's not secure as an attacker can learn information about the plaintext from that.

Comment: How does one address that then without saving a bunch of different IVs in storage somewhere. I just need a simple password based cipher leaving only the ciphertext on the phone. Should I be using a more basic algorithm than AES or saving the IV to the file somewhere

Comment: Is it reasonable to save a random IV in plaintext in the header or footer of the encrypted file?

Comment: Yes, whereever you want. It doesn't need additional protection. Usually it is just saved in front of the ciphertext though (i.e. by writing to the underlying stream). It should always have the same size as the block size (16 for AES) so there is no explicit need for meta information about it either. In Java, please make sure you don't just issue *just* one `read` command to retrieve it though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll implement and update the finalized code one more time when I get home. Should be easy to facilitate with a dataoutputstream.